# FLTK button with an image

Tags: c++, image, button, gif, fltk

I am trying to create a button using an image from the list. I want the button to be centered. My code is below. I keep getting the error " request for member ‘W’ in ‘image’, which is of non-class type ‘Fl_GIF_Image(const char*)". I am not sure what I should do. I thought this would give the width of the image. Any ideas?

```
//
//  source.cpp
//  labapril20
//
//  Created by Kate Godfrey on 4/20/17.
//  Copyright (c) 2017 Kate Godfrey. All rights reserved.
//

#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>
#include <FL/Fl_GIF_Image.H>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    srand(time(NULL)); // set random seed based on current time
    vector<string> filenames {"cloudy.gif","fog.gif","lightning.gif","partsunny.gif","rain.gif","sunny.gif"};

    string filename = filenames.at(rand() % filenames.size()); // get randome filename
    cout << "Image File: " << filename << endl; // for debugging

    // Start add code for image on button
    Fl_GIF_Image image(const char* filename);

    Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(image.W(), image.H());

    Fl_Button *button = new Fl_Button(0, 0, image.W(), image.H(), filename);
    //button->image();

    //cout << image.w() << "X" << image.h() << endl; // for debugging

    // End code for image on button
    window->end();
    window->show(argc, argv);
    return Fl::run(); 



}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about FLTK, but why using raw owning pointers? Why are you using the obsolete rand() function too?

Comment: I have the group of images saved in a folder and I want it to randomly choose one of those images to use as the button image

Comment: then have a look at the <random> library.

Comment: the issue is not with the selection of the random file. It is with assigning the image to the button

Comment: It is lowercase w and lowercase h for width and height

Comment: Your FL_GIF_Image is a prototype declaration: remove the const char* to make it a variable declaration.  Also, FL_GIF_Image takes a const char* so add a .c_str() to the end of your filename

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy to find someone who also takes Dr.Moore's class haha
try this

```
Fl_Window* w = new Fl_Window(340, 180);
Fl_GIF_Image* gif = new Fl_GIF_Image("fog.gif");
Fl_Button* Btn01 = new Fl_Button(20,40,gif->w(),gif->h());
Btn01->image(gif);
```

hope it works!